# Google App Engine Migration from V1 to V2

Tags: google-app-engine, jar, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I have migrated my Google App Engine end point. There is one jar and war file available in my V1 libs folder. But after I migrated, there is war file only available in my v2 libs folder. Without jar file I cannot proceed my work. Is anything I missed in the migration process ? Help from anyone is appreciated.

Comment: You'll have to provide more info. For example, did you follow a specific procedure documented somewhere? Edit your question please.

Comment: I have followed the migrating instructions from here.
https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/migrating-android